# Select2 Issue on Modal - JQuery - JS - FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am having an issue, where if I append the data from JQuery, it does not have format, but If I do it straight from PHP it gets the format correctly **in the same Modal.**.

So far 2 days trying to get answers by reading everywhere before asking, but I am not sure now, same code, same modal, if send by JQuery does not work, directly in PHP it does. I am not sure if is an initialization of Select2, I read a lot about that it could be, but could not figure it out how, I have tried different things, still cannot make it work via JQuery. Thank you for helping out!

Below is the code with issues:

```
.append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>State</label><select class='select2 m-b-10 select2-multiple' style='width: 100%' multiple='multiple' data-placeholder='Choose'><option value='AK'>Alaska</option><option value='HI'>Hawaii</option><option value='CA'>California</option></select></select></div></div>")
```

I need to make it work via JQuery because will pull data from AJAX - MySQL.

Thanks!

```
CalendarApp.prototype.onSelect = function (start, end, allDay) {
    var $this = this;
        $this.$modal.modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
        });
        var form = $("<form></form>");
        form.append("<div class='row'></div>");
        form.find(".row")
            .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div><label>Student</label><input list='thestud' class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Type Student' name='thestud'></div></div>")

            .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Color</label><select class='form-control' name='colors'></select></div></div>") 

            .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Notes</label><input class='form-control' placeholder='Type Notes' type='text' name='notes' required/></div></div>") 

            .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>State</label><select class='select2 m-b-10 select2-multiple' style='width: 100%' multiple='multiple' data-placeholder='Choose'><option value='AK'>Alaska</option><option value='HI'>Hawaii</option><option value='CA'>California</option></select></select></div></div>") 

            .find("select[name='colors']")
            .append("<option value='bg-success'>Green</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-danger'>Red</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-purple'>Purple</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-primary'>Pink</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-pink'>Turquoise</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-info'>Blue</option>")
            .append("<option value='bg-warning'>Orange</option></div></div>")
        $this.$modal.find('.delete-event').hide().end().find('.save-event').show().end().find('.modal-body').empty().prepend(form).end().find('.save-event').unbind('click').click(function () {
            form.submit();
        });
```

Below from php

```
<div class="modal none-border" id="my-event">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add Event</strong></h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        </div>
                                    <label class='control-label'>State</label>
                                    <select class="select2 m-b-10 select2-multiple" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose">
                                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                                </select>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light">Create event</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-event waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Below Pic of the Issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this is because the jQuery code which turns the `<select` into a `select2` object has executed before you appended the HTML containing the `<select` into your page. Therefore it didn't find any elements to attach the `select2` functionality to.

I'm not familiar with select2 specifically, but this follows a general pattern of how you work with the DOM - if you're trying to do something to an element using JavaScript, then logically that element must exist before you do it.

So please make sure you run the `select2` initialisation code *after* you've added your target `<select` element to the DOM.

(The reason it works when you used PHP of course is because the PHP generates the HTML on the server and provides it ready-made to the browser, so the `<select` will exist before the select2 initialisation code has chance to run.)

Comment: Thank you, you point me to the right answer, Instead of automatically initialize Select2 when the page load, I am doing it at the end of the Call that pull the modal, so like you said It load up everything and then initialize the Select2, working good now!. Thank you for explaining the Logic, a beer tonight on your name ;)